# Inserting image in sqlite android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

Can anybody tell me where did I get wrong with inserting image in sqlite.

here is my convertion with the image in a class:

`public class imageUtil {

```
// convert from bitmap to byte array
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(bitmap.getWidth() * bitmap.getHeight());
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, stream);
    return stream.toByteArray();
}

// convert from byte array to bitmap
public static Bitmap getImage(byte[] image) {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
}
```

}`

here is my databaseHelper:

```
package com.example.project_final.Database;
```

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public final static String DB_NAME = "db.db";

```
public final static String Table_Name = "canvass_table";

public final static String Col1 = "ID";
public final static String Col2 = "First_Name";
public final static String Col3 = "Middle_Name";
public final static String Col4 = "Last_Name";
public final static String Col5 = "Business_Type";
public final static String Col6 = "Business_Address";
public final static String Col7 = "Residential_Address";
public final static String Col8 = "Cell_Number";
public final static String Col9 = "Business_Years";
public final static String Col10 = "Customer_Pic";
public final static String Col11 = "Front_Valid_Id_Pic";
public final static String Col12 = "Back_Valid_Id_Pic";
public final static String Col13 = "Business_Location";
public final static String Col14 = "Status";


public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null,1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +Table_Name+"(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, First_Name TEXT, Middle_Name TEXT, Last_Name TEXT, " +
            "Business_Type TEXT, Business_Address TEXT, Residential_Address TEXT, Cell_Number TEXT, Business_Years TEXT,Customer_Pic BLOB NOT NULL," +
            " Front_Valid_Id_Pic BLOB NOT NULL, Back_Valid_Id_Pic BLOB NOT NULL, Business_Location BLOB NOT NULL, Status TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + Table_Name);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertData(String First_Name, String Middle_Name, String Last_Name, String Business_Type, String Business_Address,
                          String Residential_Address, String Cell_Number, String Business_Years,
                          byte[] Customer_Pic, byte[] Front_Valid_Id_Pic, byte[] Back_Valid_Id_Pic, byte[] Business_Location, String Status){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    cv.put(Col2, First_Name);
    cv.put(Col3, Middle_Name);
    cv.put(Col4, Last_Name);
    cv.put(Col5, Business_Type);
    cv.put(Col6, Business_Address);
    cv.put(Col7, Residential_Address);
    cv.put(Col8, Cell_Number);
    cv.put(Col9, Business_Years);
    cv.put(Col10, Customer_Pic);
    cv.put(Col11, Front_Valid_Id_Pic);
    cv.put(Col12, Back_Valid_Id_Pic);
    cv.put(Col13, Business_Location);
    cv.put(Col14, Status);
    long result = db.insert(Table_Name,null, cv);
    if(result == -1){
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
public Cursor viewData(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + Table_Name,null);

    return cursor;
}
```

}

and here is in activity:

```
private void ClickMe() {
    String FN = firstname.getText().toString();
    String MN = middlename.getText().toString();
    String LN = lastname.getText().toString();
    String BT = others.getText().toString();
    String BA = businessadd.getText().toString();
    String RA = residentialadd.getText().toString();
    String CN = cellnum.getText().toString();
    String BY = busyear.getText().toString();


    byte[] CP = imageUtil.getBytes(captureImage);
    byte[] FVI = imageUtil.getBytes(captureImage1);
    byte[] BVI = imageUtil.getBytes(captureImage2);
    byte[] BL = imageUtil.getBytes(captureImage3);
    String Stat = "For C.I.";

    boolean result = myDB.insertData(FN, MN, LN, BT, BA, RA, CN, BY, CP, FVI, BVI, BL, Stat);
    if (result == true) {

        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Inserted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        firstname.setText("");
        middlename.setText("");
        lastname.setText("");
        others.setText("");
        businessadd.setText("");
        residentialadd.setText("");
        cellnum.setText("");
        busyear.setText("");
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Data Insertion Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

thank you for answering! :)

Comment: what the logcat says? can you copy the logcat stacktrace to here?

Comment: `2020-06-02 15:54:50.467 29840-29840/com.example.project_final E/SQLiteLog: (1) table canvass_table has no column named Back_Valid_Id_Pic`

Comment: `2020-06-02 15:54:50.469 29840-29840/com.example.project_final E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting Status=For C.I. Middle_Name=skcjcjc Back_Valid_Id_Pic=[B@ce479ae Business_Type=Foods / Carenderia Business_Years=1 Front_Valid_Id_Pic=[B@4ef034f First_Name=sjcj Customer_Pic=[B@ae0aadc Last_Name=kccsjcjc Business_Address=shxhcs Cell_Number=09164678424 Residential_Address=bsjducjw Business_Location=[B@7dff7e5
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table canvass_table has no column named Back_Valid_Id_Pic (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR):`

Comment: @AgiMaulana i dont know where the problem is.

Comment: this is obvious that the table has no column named `Back_Valid_Id_Pic`. Have you modified the table after you've deploy it onto a device/ an emulator? if yes, you can clear the app data first or do database update to migrate your table changes

Comment: @AgiMaulana i have tried clearing the app data and still doesn't add to the database. But i haven't tried to update. Could you demonstrate to me?